# Is it safe to send Android certificate key along with source code?

Tags: android, code-signing, google-play

I just sold one of my Android apps via Apptopia. The selling process requires that I send the buyer my Android certificate key, used to sign the app.

I have several other apps which I'm not selling, that are signed using this same certificate.

Is is safe to send the key to the buyer? Is there any way they could mess with my other apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not say it is safe, but. Given that they are getting access to your key, technically it makes them possible to generate packages that can be 'uploaded' in place of your other applications, but they still do not have acces to your developer console (I am assuming you are transferring your app out of your account), so that gives you a certain degree of safety.
I know it is late, but a good practice could be to sign your apps with separate certificates in the future (which has its own drawbacks too, in certain cases). See [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945353/do-i-need-to-use-the-same-certificate-for-all-my-android-apps)

Comment: Yeah... they still wouldn't have access to my developer account. I believe publishing apps with different certificates was allowed after I published my apps, so I can do this in the future but it's too late for these.